Status 204 issue with scaffolded OpenAPI method using NSwag in Visual Studio
We're generating a C# implementation of a self-developed Web API using Visual Studio's default "Add … Connected service" method. This API returns status 204, if the request was syntactically correct, but there was no data found with the given ID. We're using TypeSpec to define the API.
For example the following method:
  @route("/{productionOrderNumber}")
  @get getOrderData(
      @path productionOrderNumber: string
  ): ProductionOrder | NoContentResponse | ProblemDetail;

It seems like NSwag doesn't handle status code 204 (no content) as a positive response, so instead of the generated method returning null, it always throws an exception. This behavior can clearly be understood after reading the method NSwag generated.
Here's the relevant part:
if (status_ == 204)
{
    string responseText_ = ( response_.Content == null ) ? string.Empty : await response_.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
    throw new ApiException("There is no content to send for this request, but the headers may be useful.", status_, responseText_, headers_, null);
}

Is there a way to reconfigure NSwag and make it understand status 204 to be a positive response. I don't want to modify the auto-generated code as it can change often.

did you check this https://github.com/RicoSuter/NSwag/issues/1259 and  https://github.com/RicoSuter/NSwag/issues/2499?form=MG0AV3?

@RomanMarusyk I already found those posts. No solution there unfortunately.

what about using OperationFilter?

@RomanMarusyk How does that work?

you said that you checked the link above, there is the asnwer

@RomanMarusyk Either I'm misunderstading that solution, or we can't use it as we don't use swagger but TypeSpec to generate the OpenAPI yaml file.
